# Imagem reserva - SRC

Tags: php, javascript, html, img

Estou com duvidas se é possível criar uma imagem secundaria caso a imagem principal não existir

No caso, se alguem se registrar e não colocar foto, ele setar uma img padrão.

```php
<img src="assets/images/<?= $username ?>.png" alt="" class="user-avatar-md rounded-circle">
```

tem alguma possibilidade de eu poder fazer 2 SRC ? e quando o arquivo nome.png não for encontrado ele substituir por

```html
<img src="assets/images/avatar-1.jpg" alt="" class="user-avatar-md rounded-circle">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode verificar no próprio PHP se o arquivo da imagem existe:

```
<img src="assets/images/<?=file_exists("$username.png") ? "$username.png" : "avatar-1.jpg" ?>" alt="" class="user-avatar-md rounded-circle">
```

O `file_exists("$username.png")` irá buscar a imagem PNG com o nome na variável `$username`, se não encontrar, irá mostrar a imagem `avatar-1.jpg`. Mas só irá funcionar se a opção `allow_url_fopen` estiver `on` no php.ini.

Answer (score -1):

Simples, faça um `if` verificando se a variável `$username` tem algum valor, que no caso é o nome da imagem, caso não exista conteúdo na variável adicione o link para a imagem padrão.

```
<?php
 if(!isset($username)){
 $username = "link/para/imagem/padrão";
 } 
?>
```

Comment: todas variavel "$username" tem valor, mas nos arquivos do site, a imagem pode não existir, então ele vai retornar o valor, exemplo: teste.png, mas no site não existe teste.png, então ele ia ficar sem imagem

Comment: Uai, pq o seu edit copiou a solução da minha resposta? E ainda colocou uma solução capenga.

Comment: kkkkk, nem percebi.
Mais respeito com minha resposta. Vou "deseditar"

Comment: Mas vc tem como ver quem respondeu primeiro? nem tinha notado sua reposta.